# How to query many-to-many relationship with 'AND' condition using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My current database solution includes three tables called `Establishment`, `Feature`, and a linking many-to-many table called `EstablishmentFeature` (since an establishment can have many features, and a feature can exists across multiple establishments).

I need to generate a query that returns establishments that meet only certain criteria, namely, which establishments have X features based on a collection of featureId's being passed in.  The establishment must have ALL features that are being search, i.e.. `AND` not `OR` condition.

I got the SQL to achieve the desired result, but I am pulling my hair out trying to work out the LINQ (lambra prefereably) equivalent.  The T-SQL is:

```
SELECT e.[EstablishmentId], e.[Name], e.[Description]
FROM Establishment e
INNER JOIN EstablishmentFeature ef
ON e.[EstablishmentId] = ef.[EstablishmentId]
WHERE ef.[FeatureId]  in ('20', '15', '72')
GROUP BY e.[EstablishmentId], e.[Name], e.[Description] 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

I tried to use Linqer to convert the SQL but Linqer crashes when it attempts the conversion.  I tried reinstalling Linqer, but it crashes without fail when trying to compile the LINQ syntax.  (Simpler conversions work though).  Also tried to work out the LINQ equivalent using LinqPad, but I just ended up chasing my tail...

Is this something I will have to use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for?  Somewhat exhausted, I don't want to go through the PredicateBuilder learning curve if there is a simple solution that is escaping me.

Comment: We need to see your DBContext structure to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try this (For **all** given ids there is **any** (= at least one) feature that has this given id):

```
var establishments = context.Establishments
    .Where(e => featureIds.All(fid => e.Features.Any(f => f.FeatureId == fid)))
    .ToList();
```

(`featureIds` is an `IEnumerable<int>` with the Ids being searched for.)